# change element's style on ngClick directly in the view

Tags: angularjs

I KNOW this is not really the angular's paradigm but I really need to do the following :

```
<div ng-click="this.style.opacity=0;">click/hide me</div>
```

However, `this` is not recognized, how can I change the opacity with a javascript inline instruction when I click the element *(without using ngClass as well !)*

Answer (score 2):

Just Try

```
<div ng-click="myStyle={'opacity':0}" ng-style="myStyle">click/hide me</div>
```

Comment: hmm not tested yet, but I wish I could do that only in ng-click. yeah call me a greedy

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use only ng-click ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div id="myId" ng-click="setOpacity()">click/hide me</div>
```

and inside your controller:

```
$scope.setOpacity = function(){
  document.getElementById("myId").style.opacity = 0; //pure JS
  $('#myId").fadeTo(0,0); //Jquery
}
```

not tested, but this should do the job. alternatively you can use the following expression:

```
$scope.setOpacity = function(){
  $('#myId").hide();
}
```

this also should work.

Comment: You haven't defined `myId` in your code. I presume you meant `"myId"`. You should use `$scope.setOpacity = function($event) { $($event.currentTarget).css({opacity: 0}); }` then you don't need to pass the id.

Comment: of course you are right, i just corrected it. Your solution is better then mine :D very smart :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to hide the element and never see it again then use this.

```
<div ng-click="hide = true" ng-hide="hide">click/hide me</div>
```

Don't forget to set hide to false to begin with...

```
$scope.hide = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do following

Add CSS

```
.hide {
    opacity: 0
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-click="myStyle = 'hide'" ng-class="myStyle">click/hide me</div>
```